# Can I make money from the mortgage?

Tags: mortgage, payment, profitability

I have this question:
Let's say I bought a house for $100k.

Now after 5 years the value of the house went up from $100k to $150k. Can I go to the bank and ask for the additional $50k added to the mortgage(which increases my monthly payments) and the bank will give me $50k in cash? Which adds up to my savings.

Comment: Search the Internet for phrases such as "Home Equity Line of Credit" and "Refinance my mortgage"

Comment: @DilipSarwate is HELOC a private business or is it part of every bank?

Comment: Just to be clear, borrowing money is not the same as making money.

Comment: @Grasper HELOC is not a company. It is a type of loan that most banks offer.

Comment: Note that if your property value went up by $50000, you would usually be able to borrow against 80% of the increase in equity unless you pay Mortgage Insurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can request for additional loan and it would be given as cash. You are free to do whatever you like with it.

This does not mean Bank will automatically grant you loan. They would ask you purpose, check your ability to make additional repayments, verify if the property has actually appreciated before deciding.

Note this is not savings. This makes sense only if you can generate returns greater than the cost of loan.

Comment: I would use the money to remodel, add addition which would increase the value beyond $200k, so it is some form of making money. Investment?

Comment: Remodeling rarely produces a profit.

Comment: @Grasper That depends on what addition and how the market in general would react to it.

Comment: @keshlam, I know people I lived with. They bought a house in UK for $100k, invested $50k in remodeling and sold for $500K. No kidding. They did it 8 times like this.

Comment: the value of your home has no meaning, when you're not willing to sell. You're just spending money for a fancier place. Which is ok, just don't justify it with investment returns

Comment: @keshlam, just because something doesn't work for you does not mean it doesn't work for others that do it properly!

Comment: @MarkDoony: Real estate industry statistics _strongly_ argue that most renovations cost more than they will return, unless they are gut-rehabs of property that was bought cheap or that has unusually high land value. There ate exceptions, but the near-universal recommendation is to renovate only because it's cheaper than moving to get what you want.

Comment: Note too that the time of rapid flip for profit is _gone_. The law of the ultimate sucker ran out; that's what caused the housing crash and the Great Recedsion. You can still make a profit in real estate -- but you ___really___ should not count the house you're living in as part of that; it's a double-accounting error that will come back to bite you.

Comment: @keshlam, like I said just because it doesn't work for some who don't know what they are doing, for others it does work, and timing can make the difference.

Comment: @markdoony: My point -- which we agree on -- is that it can not be assumed to work in the general case. If you have a specific case where you've thought that through in detail, you don't need this warning. If you're asking a general question without those specifics, as the OP has, I think you really do.